# Foreach duplicate value

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on a file sharing system. I have the following result from my query and when I use `print_r()` I get the desired data but the problem is that i don't know how to display it a specific format

**My database schema..**

```
table folder 

    ID    folder_name    path
    1     tep            dulay

table files 

       ID   file_name   path 
       1    1.jpg       dulay
       2    2.jpg       dulay
```

**Desired result** must be something similar to dropbox.com

```
My files
tep folder         
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

The query seems to be correct but when I display it. It outputs like below. I think the reason is that I have 2 files that is why it repeats the folder tpp inside the loop.

```
My files    
tep folder            
tep folder
1.jpg 
2.jpg
```

I think the problem is in my foreach loop.

**PHP Code..**

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <th>Folder NAME</th>
        <th>FILES</th>
        <?php 
        foreach($my_files as $key )
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $key->folder_name?></td>
            <td><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>filesharing/<?php echo $key->path?>/<?php echo $key->file_name?>" download="<?php echo $key->file_name;?>"><?php echo $key->file_name?></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

**My Query**

```
$data['my_files'] = $this->db->select('folders.folder_name,files.file_name,files.owner,files.path')->from('folders')->join('files','files.path=folders.path','left outer')->where('folders.path',$url)->get()->result();
```

Comment: What value is duplicated. Very unclear what your actual issue is

Comment: Please add desired output. so that we can understand better.

Comment: I've added my desired output

Comment: I am really more confused about the second part of the output. Did you have more data in array. Please post appropriate data. so that we can found out what actually you want to achieve.

Comment: Also is your resultset sorted on folder_name?

Comment: Did you want that the duplicate filename is also not repeated?.......

Comment: @geeksal yes. see my html code. I will edit my post

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the output required is like as you stated in the first block

```
  **folder_name**    **file_name**   
          tep        1.jpg
                     2.jpg
```

You can achieve this in simple way, You just need to check that if folder_name is same than push files in same array.

I am assuming you have this array of objects in mysql response.

```
$mysql_response = Array ( 

[0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [folder_name] => tep 
        [file_name] => 1.jpg 
        [owner] => dulay 
        [path] => dulay )
[1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [folder_name] => tep 
        [file_name] => 2.jpg 
        [owner] => dulay 
        [path] => dulay ) 
);
```

PHP Code implementation:

```
<?php

$filefolders = array();
foreach($mysql_response as $key => $fileObject){
     $filefolders[$fileObject->folder_name][] = $fileObject->file_name;
}

?>
```

HTML Listings of folders and all files inside each folder.

```
<table>
<tr><th>Folder Name</th><th>File Name</th></tr>
<?php foreach($filefolders as $folder => $file){ ?> 
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $folder; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $file; ?></td> 
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the output required is like as you stated in the first block

```
  folder_name    file_name
  tep            1.jpg
                 2.jpg
```

OR

```
  folder_name    file_name
  tep            1.jpg
  jonnas
```

Try this code, it keeps track of duplicated folder and files so that the name of such folder and file is displayed only once.

```
 <?php
    $prevFolder=null;
    $prevFile=null; 
    foreach($my_files as $key )
    {
      echo '<tr>';
     if($key->folder_name!=$prevFolder){
         echo '<td>'.$key->folder_name.'</td>';
         $prevFolder=$key->folder_name;
     }
     else{
          echo '<td></td>';
     }

     if($key->file_name!=$prevFile){
         echo '<td><a href="'.base_url().'filesharing/'.$key->path.'/'.$key->file_name.'" download="'.$key->file_name.'">'.$key->file_name.'</a></td>';
         $prevFile=$key->file_name;
     }
     else{
          echo '<td></td>';
     }
  ?> 

    </tr>
    <?php 
    }
    ?>
```

**Note: To achieve proper output all the times. It is advised that the result are sorted by file_name or folder_name***

Comment: the file name duplicated even its one. I mean it reversed

Comment: @JonasDulay Please clarify what you want. Edit your question to reflect desired output.

Comment: at first it is okay but when I add a new value in the file folder it becomes like this http://imgur.com/5XLanjD

Comment: @JonasDulay see my note and check the issue in you query.

Comment: I dont know how to sort it :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111299/discussion-between-jonas-dulay-and-geeksal).

Comment: @JonasDulay use `order by folder_name` or  `order by file_name` at the end of the query.